# AppWidget PendingIntent not working after Launcher restart

Tags: android, android-intent, onclick, android-appwidget, android-pendingintent

I have an AppWidget with 2 pending intents. They work most of the time, but after a while they stop responding. Only thing I have been able to pinpoint is that they are crippled after a Launcher restart, i.e. I use Launcher Pro, and sometimes fiddle with settings and have to restart it. After that they don't work at all.

Here are my `onRecieve()` and `onUpdate()` methods:

```
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if(action.equals("android.tristan.widget.digiclock.CLICK"))
    {
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        Intent alarmClockIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        String clockImpls[][] = {
                {"HTC Alarm Clock", "com.htc.android.worldclock", "com.htc.android.worldclock.AlarmClock" },
                {"Standar Alarm Clock", "com.android.deskclock", "com.android.deskclock.AlarmClock"},
                {"Froyo Nexus Alarm Clock", "com.google.android.deskclock", "com.android.deskclock.DeskClock"},
                {"Moto Blur Alarm Clock", "com.motorola.blur.alarmclock",  "com.motorola.blur.alarmclock.AlarmClock"}
        };

        boolean foundClockImpl = false;

        for(int i=0; i<clockImpls.length; i++) {
            String vendor = clockImpls[i][0];
            String packageName = clockImpls[i][1];
            String className = clockImpls[i][2];
            try {
                ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(packageName, className);
                ActivityInfo aInfo = packageManager.getActivityInfo(cn, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                alarmClockIntent.setComponent(cn);
                foundClockImpl = true;
            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d(LOGTAG, "Error," + vendor + " does not exist");
            }
        }

        if (foundClockImpl) {
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(50);
        final RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), layoutID);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.TopRow, PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, DigiClock.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
        AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS), views);
        alarmClockIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(alarmClockIntent);       
   }
    }
}

        public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    context.startService(new Intent(UpdateService.ACTION_UPDATE));
    context.startService(new Intent(context, ScreenUpdateService.class));
    final int Top = appWidgetIds.length;
    final int Bottom = appWidgetIds.length;
    for (int i=0; i<Top; i++)
    {
    int[] appWidgetId = appWidgetIds;
    final RemoteViews top=new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), layoutID);
    Intent clickintent=new Intent("android.tristan.widget.digiclock.CLICK");
    PendingIntent pendingIntentClick=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, clickintent, 0);
    top.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.TopRow, pendingIntentClick);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, top);
}
for (int i=0; i<Bottom; i++)
{
    int[] appWidgetId = appWidgetIds;
    RemoteViews bottom=new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), layoutID);
    Intent clickintent=new Intent("android.tristan.widget.digiclock.CLICK_2");
    PendingIntent pendingIntentClick=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, clickintent, 0);
    bottom.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.BottomRow, pendingIntentClick);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, bottom);
}
}
```

I have read about putting the intents in a service, but have tried and failed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what's with the call to `super.onUpdate();` ? It does not do anything according to the source http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.java#113 .

Comment: `appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget()` does not need to be called in a loop for every widget. It accepts an integer array. So you could simply call `appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, top)` once instead of `appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, top)` multiple times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Widget not updated on launcher restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650553/widget-not-updated-on-launcher-restart)

Answer (score 4):

As I've written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650553/widget-not-updated-on-launcher-restart/) you should only produce a single instance of the RemoteView.

Comment: Not really, creating a single instance will cause widget to collapse eventually; as the memory will increase with each instruction sent to the remote view

Answer (score 0):

`PendingIntent.getBroadcast` has an argument called `requestCode`, it must be a unique code in case of multiple `PendingIntent`.
you've set it to 0 for all of your `PendingIntents`.